# Apache configuration so images are cached for a long time

Tags: apache-httpd, caching

I'm asking here since no matter what I try I keep noticing images keep being reloaded after a while. Basically I want images to be cached for 11 months, but if anything they seem to be cached for minutes or hours. This is a node.js application with static files served by apache. The images are inside the public/static dir. This is what I have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName app.site.com

  ProxyPreserveHost   On

  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}

  Alias "/static/" "/home/node/app/public/static/"

  <Directory /home/node/app/public>

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 11 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 11 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 11 months"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 11 months"

  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)                  ws://localhost:3210/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(?!static/)(.*)$ http://localhost:3210/$1 [P,L]

  SSLCertificateFile /root/.lego/certificates/_.site.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/.lego/certificates/_.site.com.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Having the console open and reloading to catch network activity shows this on a random image:

```
200 OK

Response header:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 10:27:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 01 Jun 2020 19:03:16 GMT
ETag: "3313-5a70a727f2500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 13075
Cache-Control: max-age=28512000
Expires: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 10:27:50 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png

Request header:

GET /static/img/profile_5a914158141c9367e38c4d8a.png?ver=74 HTTP/1.1
Host: hue.merkoba.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://app.site.com/
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AUZb7Zopuy6LId0iMeMYVaKDtfuppIIxL.8F7Hx%2FeqrodOsS2fHPZjOqRDKTBM4RoBwcKiUu0PUUg; io=fbMMZAHDTJzbnoVvAAAo
Cache-Control: max-age=0
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 01 Jun 2020 19:03:16 GMT
If-None-Match: "3313-5a70a727f2500"
```

Some curl test:

```
curl -vso /dev/null https://app.site.com/static/img/profile_5f192733805c646004ecf4c8.png?ver=1
*   Trying 196.83.125.124:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app.site.com (192.81.135.159) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [112 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2391 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [147 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.site.com
*  start date: May 14 20:51:05 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 12 20:51:05 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "app.site.com" matched cert's "*.site.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /static/img/profile_5f192733805c646004ecf4c8.png?ver=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.site.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 10:30:40 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 06:01:07 GMT
< ETag: "16f27-5ab15950eeec0"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 93991
< Cache-Control: max-age=28512000
< Expires: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 10:30:40 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
< 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host app.site.com left intact
```